# cross-build artifacts being built but not with `releaseCrossBuild := true`

Tags: scala, sbt-release, sbt-sonatype, scala-version-cross-build

I'm trying to release a version of https://github.com/guardian/marley cross-built for Scala v2.11 & v2.12. All code dependencies are satisfied, and both `+test` and `+publishLocalSigned` work as expected, the latter definitely producing artifacts for Scala v2.11 & v2.12. Unfortunately, executing [`sbt release`](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-release) with the [`sbt-sonatype`](https://github.com/xerial/sbt-sonatype) plugin only *uploads* artifacts for Scala v2.12 - it makes no attempt to upload artifacts for Scala v2.11 to the sonatype staging repository.

Here are the relevant sbt settings from the `build.sbt` file ([full version in the repo on GitHub](https://github.com/guardian/marley/blob/5ff877a2c85b0981e2c566f1ee16b9823bfca5eb/build.sbt)):

```
scalaVersion in ThisBuild := "2.12.4"

crossScalaVersions in ThisBuild := Seq(scalaVersion.value, "2.11.12")

import ReleaseTransformations._

releaseCrossBuild := true // true if you cross-build the project for multiple Scala versions
releaseProcess := Seq[ReleaseStep](
  checkSnapshotDependencies,
  inquireVersions,
  runClean,
  runTest,
  setReleaseVersion,
  commitReleaseVersion,
  tagRelease,
  releaseStepCommand("publishSigned"),
  setNextVersion,
  commitNextVersion,
  releaseStepCommand("sonatypeReleaseAll"),
  pushChanges
)
```

Here's a full copy of the `sbt release` command output: https://gist.github.com/rtyley/5f9f832fabe2bdcfc2d561a36c29f993 - you can see that even though `[info] Setting scala version to 2.11.12` occurs (twice) - only Scala 2.12 artifacts are uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is the `releaseStepCommand("publishSigned")` in your release process.

I think either:

- it needs to be `releaseStepCommand("+publishSigned")`; or
- you need to instead set `releasePublishArtifactsAction := PgpKeys.publishSigned.value`, and switch back to `publishArtifacts` (instead of using `releaseStepCommand`)

The README documents the `releasePublishArtifactsAction` way.

Comment: Thanks for responding Dale! Unfortunately no luck... I tried `releaseStepCommand("+publishSigned")` with https://github.com/guardian/marley/commit/d4f62deee (crashed out with `No staging repository is found. Do publishSigned first.`...!?) and also `releasePublishArtifactsAction := PgpKeys.publishSigned.value` which seemed to make no difference - the Scala 2.12 artifacts were already being signed before, and `releasePublishArtifactsAction` (https://github.com/guardian/marley/commit/98b7bf77) didn't change the the fact that the Scala 2.11 artifacts weren't being uploaded... :(

Comment: @RobertoTyley try `releasePublishArtifactsAction := PgpKeys.publishSigned.value` again, but switch back to `publishArtifacts` instead of `releaseStepCommand`.

Comment: How about using `releaseStepCommandAndRemaining("+publishSigned")` ?

Comment: Yes, @leo! That makes sense now that you mention it.